# Conjugate transpose of self using numpy syntax

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am trying to translate this MATLAB code into Python.

The following is the code:

```
Y=C*Up(:,1:p-1)'*Y;
```

And this is my translation thus far:

```
Y = C * Up[:, 1:p-1] * Y
```

I am having trouble with the syntax for the conjugate transpose of self that is used in the MATLAb code. I am not certain that my first idea:

```
Y = C * Up[:, 1:p-1].getH() * Y
```

would be correct.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs for the matrix (matrices)?

Comment: `1:p-1` - remember, python indexing is 0 based, MATLAB 1 based.

Comment: Is `Up` (possibly) complex?  If not then plain `transpose` is enough.  I was going to warn about transpose not doing anything to 1d arrays, but `Up` is evidently 2d,  Also what kind of multiplication do you want?  Matrix or element wise?  MATLAB and numpy have different operators for those.

Comment: `.getH` is a method for `np.matrix` subclass.  `np.matrix` is MATLAB like (including its definition of `*`), it's use in `numpy` is discouraged.  `Up.T.conjugte()` will do the same for `ndarray` objects.  Of course the `conjugate` part is needed only if `Up` is complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not very experienced with numpy, but based on the comments of **@hpaulj** I can suggest the following:

If you don't want to be subject to the limitations of `numpy.matrix` objects (see warning [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#index-0)), you can define your own function for doing a conjugate transpose. All you need to do is transpose your array, then subtract the imaginary part of the result, times 2, from the result. I am not sure how computationally efficient this is, but it should definitely give the correct result.

I'd expect something like this to work:

```
Y = C * ctranspose(Up[:, 0:p-1]) * Y

...

def ctranspose(arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # Explanation of the math involved:
    # x      == Real(X) + j*Imag(X)
    # conj_x == Real(X) - j*Imag(X)
    # conj_x == Real(X) + j*Imag(X) - 2j*Imag(X) == x - 2j*Imag(X)
    tmp = arr.transpose()
    return tmp - 2j*tmp.imag
```

(Solution is for Python 3)

---

A more elegant solution based on the comment by **@AndrasDeak**:

```
Y = C * Up[:, 0:p-1].conj().T * Y
```

---

Note also, two differences related to indexing between python and MATLAB:

- Python is 0-based (i.e. the first index of an array is `0`, unlike in MATLAB where it's `1`)
- The indexing in Python is `inclusive:exclusive` unlike in MATLAB where it's `inclusive:inclusive`.

Therefore, when we want to access the first 3 elements of a vector in MATLAB we'd write:

```matlab
res = vec(1:3);
```

In Python we'd write:

```py
res = vec[0:3] # or [:3]
```

(Again, credits to @Andras for this explanation)

Comment: Why not `arr.conj().T`?

Comment: Elementary my dear @Andras - because I didn't know that such a function exists :)

Comment: Also `*` only does matmul if OP has `np.matri`ces, otherwise they need `@`.

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you for your thorough explanation and help!

Answer (score 1):

Use arr.conj().T to get complex conjugate of a matrix.